# uninstalling vim-minimal also uninstalls sudo in Centos 7.4

Tags: linux, vim, centos, sudo, yum

Setting up a new CentOS 7.4 machine. I installed vim using `sudo yum install vim`, and then I uninstalled `vim-minimal` with `sudo yum remove vim-minimal`.  Now `sudo` has been uninstalled:

```
$ sudo
-bash: /usr/bin/sudo: No such file or directory
```

What happened? Is `sudo` really part of the `vim-minimal` package?   How can I reinstall it, now that I don't have sudo anymore? I don't know the root password.

Answer (score 0):

sudo is not a part of vim-minimal however the dependency is linked between them. 
see here for more details.

https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?292058-sudo-packages-requires-vim-minimal

after a little searching it seems you can use

```
 pkexec yum install sudo    (sudo password will be required) ** edit,see bottom
```

to reinstall sudo; 
also, you could have used

```
 rpm -e --no-deps vim-minimal
```

to remove vim-minimal without removing sudo also. 
Hope it helps. See you

edit :  if you cant get access to the root password in any way, you can try..

- boot into recovery mode: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode
- Drop to root shell: one of the options in recovery mode
- install sudo
- reboot

hope it helps.

Comment: ah, sorry, just saw that you dont know the root password ... cant you get it somehow? or ask the admin responsible to enter it for you?